# Converting Displacement-Time to Distance-Graph for Simple Harmonic Motion

Tags: kinematics, harmonic-oscillator, displacement

An object undergoes simple harmonic motion with the position/displacement function
$$Position=\text{sin } t$$

The distance function is:
\begin{equation}
Distance = d(t)=
\left\{
    \begin{array}{lr}
        \text{sin } x ,\text{if } 0 \leq t < \frac{\pi}{2}\\
        2- \text{sin } x ,\text{if } \frac{\pi}{2} \leq t < pi\\
    \end{array}
\right\}
\end{equation}

[image]

How do I justify this distance-time graph. It just "looks" right. But is there a justify it using logic, and/or maths. Ideally, two different answers that do it both ways would be appreciated.

Comment: to get distance-from-equilibrium d-vs-time from displacement-from-equilibrium x-vs-time, use d(t)=abs( x(t) ).

Comment: @robphy I understand how to do this if I break it up piecewise. But are you saying that abs(x(t)) will convert from displacement to distance throughout? Because in the second interval displacement is positive, but decreasing.

Comment: go to desmos.com.  Plot sin(x) and abs(sin(x))... and 2-sin(x).

Comment: I already plotted it in geogbra, and put the graph in question.